# Webservice different request design

Tags: web-services

I'm a very beginner in webservices development and I would like to ask a design question to understand what's the best approach.
I have to create a webservice which will return some objects to the user, and it has to work like that:

- Request: Give me the red apples in the system

  Response: 5 Red Apples. Found Also 3 green apples. Should I return them too?

  Request: Yes -> response return 8 apples

  Request: No -> response return 5 apples

Would you use a single webservice to do that? If so, what's the best way to keep track of the current state? (I was thinking of 2 flags into the request/response but i don't know if it's a good idea..)

Answer (score 0):

You would certainly use a single web service to do that, although you may choose to implement more than one operations (methods) in it.

State management will typically require some form of storage - you could use a database or an in-memory cache, and you will need to consider things such as handing scale, high-avialabilty, clean-up routines etc.

To correlate between request you will require to pass some token around, typically this will be provided by either the first request or first response and then re-used in subsequent calls, which would allow the service to pull the relevant context

Because standards exist to support this sort of implementation various frameworks and languages have built-in support for this, I would look for something in the relevant technology you use for implementation.

Last, but not least, typically when thinking about web implementations, state is undesirable, so - whenever possible opt for a stateless implementation. one where the requestor can issue a brand new request to get the next lot of data, without the service needing to remember anything.